Understand which measurements is a detector looking at in Stim
In stim, I normally define detectors as DETECTOR rec[-1] rec[-2]. In the timeline plot, detectors are written in explicit forms like D1=rec[2]*rec[3], and each measurement is labelled with rec indices.
I wonder if there is a way to get this info in my code so I don't have to zoom in on the plot and try to find all the labels. I tried some compile functions, but they still show negative indices.

This would be a reasonable method to implement. It currently does not exist.
The closest workaround would be to ensure there is a TICK instruction before and after your measurement instructions, call stim.Circuit.detecting_regions, and look at the detector sensitivities that appear in the TICK before the measurement but not in the TICK after the measurement (or vice versa) as this indicates they must have gone into or come out of the measurement.
